# persisting objects in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

Completley new to sp and trying to create a timer job that uses a value stored in a persisted object.  I found some examples but for some reason when my job runs the persisted object is always null.  My code is below

code to retrieve the object

```
 ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings Settings = WebApplication.GetChild<ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings>(ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings.SettingsName);

 if (Settings == null) {
      return;
}
```

code in the feature activated event

```
        ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings =
            WebApplication.GetChild<ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings>(ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings.SettingsName);

        //only create a new settings object if there isnt one.
        if (ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings == null) {
            ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings = new ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings(WebApplication, Guid.NewGuid());
            ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings.CurrentIncrement = 10;
            ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings.Update();
        }
```

my persisted object definition

```
   public class ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings : SPPersistedObject {
            public static string SettingsName = "ContentDatabaseIncrementorTimerJobSettings";

            public ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings() : base() { }
            public ContentDataBaseIncrementorJobSettings(SPPersistedObject parent, Guid id) : base(SettingsName, parent, id) { }

            [Persisted]
            public int CurrentIncrement;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per MSDN thread "To return an existing persisted object, use the GetObject method of the SPFarm class, or the GetChild method of the SPPersistedObject class". 
Try using WebApplication.SPFarm.GetObject()